# Anonymous sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have code like this, where sympy functions are passed into a list:

```
    if name == "sqrt":
        func.append(sympy.sqrt)
    elif name == "abs":
        funcs.append(sympy.Abs)
    elif name == "sin":
        funcs.append(sympy.sin)
    elif name == "cos":
        funcs.append(sympy.cos)
    elif name == "tan":
        funcs.append(sympy.tan)
    elif name == "exp":
        funcs.append(sympy.exp)
```

and so on. I need to replace (I know this isn't proper syntax) `sympy.exp(x)` with `sympy.Min(1, sympy.exp(x))`. How can I do this so that the argument is implicit and I can add it to the list, like with the built-in functions?

Comment: All those cases where `name` is the same as the function can be covered by `funcs.append(getattr(sympy, name))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda expressions: `funcs.append(lambda x: sympy.Min(1, sympy.exp(x)))`

Comment: That's what I thought, but doesn't that mess up the symbolic stuff? Like printing and whatever.

Comment: Mmm, `type((lambda x: sympy.Min(1, sympy.exp(x)))(1))` is `<class 'sympy.core.numbers.One'>` - is that not okay? Not too familiar with sympy.

Comment: You can use `sympy.Lambda(x, sympy.Min(1, sympy.exp(x))` to create a symbolic lambda.